# Unable to return text between two different strings

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to use Excel to get text between specific text

> ALERT [ NewStrat ]\n\nSpanish La Liga / Celta Vigo v Valladolid\nFeb
> 28 at 13:00\n\nMatch Odds: 2.64 / 5.7 / 2.22 ( Â£280,985 )\nAt
> kick-off: 1.95 / 4.6 / 3.6\n\nUnder/Over 1.5: 1.37 / 3.55 ( Â£21,920
> )\nAt kick-off: 3.45 / 1.4\n\nUnder/Over 2.5: 1.09 / 11 ( Â£52,397
> )\nAt kick-off: 1.81 / 2.2\n\nCorrect Score: ( Â£18,423 )\n\nScore: 0

In the Example above I would like to get the teams playing (Celta Vigo v Valladolid).

I use the following but it returns a blank cell and im sure its due to this part of the string

> SEARCH("\n"

I have to seach by \n as this is the only part of the text that will be the same across other text

```
=IFERROR(MID($C$2,SEARCH("Spanish La Liga",$C$2)+LEN("Spanish La Liga"),SEARCH("\n",$C$2)-SEARCH("Spanish La Liga",$C$2)-LEN("Spanish La Liga")), "")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with a shorter/less verbose formula, but the nice thing to do here is to use the delimiters in the text for what they were meant to be, delimiters of some sort. `\n` was probably used as a newline character in the source of this text, but we can now utilize `FILTERXML()` to split your input again on this pattern:

```
=MID(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\n","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[starts-with(., 'Spanish La Liga')]"),19,LEN(A1))
```

I used `A1` as a placeholder for whichever cell you were refering to. The way it works is that we used `SUBSTITUTE()` to create a a valid XML-string full of start/end-tags. The xpath expression then looks for the element that starts with "Spanish La Liga". A simple `MID()` function then takes care of the string operation to only report the relevant part.

Comment: Worked perfect thanks

What is this part doing "</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s